# Mac forgetting multiple monitor settings

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I have a MBP running ML. I have 2 extra monitors. one is attached via the mini display port, and i never have problems with it. the other is attached via usb and a displaylink adaptor. combine that with my laptop screen and I have a very nice 3 monitor set-up. The problem is, every second or third time I plug my monitors in, my computer forgets the wallpaper and color settings for the displaylink monitor, I would chalk it up to being an adaptor issue and say "such is life with a hack" but what gets me is it NEVER forgets the settings for position relative to the other monitors. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: For what it's worth, the problem went away with Mavericks.